# Python: read mixed data from text file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a simple text file with two columns. Example line:
'J0005-28'  14719.0
I want to read line by line the first entry as text, and the second as a number, so I can set variables like name= 'J0005-28' and value= 14719.0

Is there a simple way to do this in Python without using Regex or other complicated parsing processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to know the structure of the lines in the file. How are the fields you want to separate out, delimited in the file. In your example, if you are sure that fields are delimited by spaces, you can use python's `csv` module and set the delimiter to space and parse the lines.

Sample code:

```
import csv

names = []
values = []

with open(input_file, 'r') as infile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
    for line in csv_reader:
        names.append(line[0])
        values.append(line[1])
infile.close()
```

Comment: 1. I'm using tab delimiters and have set it in the call
2. I need to convert the second column entries back to numbers using values.append(float(line[1])).
Otherwise, it works well.
I was thinking there might be a single line method (like genfromtxt or loadtxt, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

yeah sure, first of all read the whole line and then extract out the data separately. For Example:

```
f=open('abc.txt','r')
while 1:
    a=f.readline()
    if a=='': break
    a=a.split()                  #This creates a list of the input
    name=a[0]
    value=int(a[1])              # or value=float(a[1]) whatever you want
    #use the name and value howsoever
f.close()
```

Comment: Oh yeah, as said by warunsl, in case space is not the delimiter, you can set it by a.split('whatever delimiter') example. a.split('|')

Comment: Actually if you are sure there is going to be some fixed delimiter, you can always use csv and set the delimiter flag of the reader function appropriately. The csv reader automatically splits based on the delimiter and populates it as a list.

Comment: ahh well, i'm a bit of newbie, so bear with me, but isn't that what split() too does...??